# Java add external jar to classpath at runtime using Module api

Tags: java, module, classloader

In java 16+ its no longer possible, without modyfing program startup flags, to add external jar to classpath with invoking ClassLoader#addUrl method with reflection.

With release of Java 9 a new Module API (java.lang.module) has been added that, from my raw understanding, should do all this heavy lifting for us.

```
    public void addPath(Path dir) {

        ModuleFinder pluginsFinder = ModuleFinder.of(dir);
        List<String> plugins = pluginsFinder
                .findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(ModuleReference::descriptor)
                .map(ModuleDescriptor::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Configuration pluginsConfiguration = ModuleLayer
                .boot()
                .configuration()
                .resolve(pluginsFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), plugins);


        ModuleLayer layer = ModuleLayer
                .boot()
                .defineModulesWithOneLoader(pluginsConfiguration, getClass().getClassLoader());

    }
```

And now testing this code.

For the sake of example I`ll be using graal binaries during this test.

```
Class c = layer.findLoader("org.graalvm.sdk").loadClass("org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine"); 
// c is not null and contains correct reference to the graal`s Engine class

Class.forName("org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine");
//Throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Why does Class.forName throws Exception, but the first test does not?

And my second question can i use the module api to get list of all classes that can be loaded by the layer loader? For now im testing this on graal, but later ill need to scan all loaded jars and search for all classes having specific annotation.

Comment: `layer.findLoader("org.graalvm.sdk")` might not return the current class loader.

Comment: yes, it doesnt despite me setting the correct classloader in defineModulesWithOneLoader method

Comment: Why do you assume that `Class.forName(String)` will use your newly created module layer?

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate your own URLClassLoader to load the desired class?

Comment: Concerning you second question: AFAIK it is not possible to see annotations by scanning the jar. I think you need to load every single class from the jar so see the annotations. Not a big deal with a custom classloader, but a quite expensive operation (but may be worth the effort - depending on what you want to achieve)

Comment: Those are two different classloaders.  But you can create your own classloader to add external jars at runtime.